# show that there exists a set $S$ satisfying an inequality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> In the solution to the problem shown below, why can they assume WLOG that $s_{i_1} + s_{i_2} \ge -(t_{i_1} + t_{i_2})$? I tried proving the result in the case where this doesn't hold by showing that $-(s_{i_1} + s_{i_2}) + t_{i_1} \leq -s/6$ or $-(s_{i_1} + s_{i_2}) + t_{i_2})\leq -s/6$ (which would hold if their sum was at most $-s/3$) but I wasn't able to make much progress.

> Also when they set $r_1 = r_2 = r_3 = 1, r_4 = r_5 = r_6 = -1,$ why is $\frac{1}6$ the best possible value for the bound?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice question, and answer [both upvoted]. What book or paper was the source of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the solution to the problem shown below, why can they assume WLOG that $s_{i_1} + s_{i_2} \ge -(t_{i_1} + t_{i_2})$?

Because if the theorem to be proved works for $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^n$, it will also work for $\{-r_k\}_{k=1}^n$. Negating the $r_k$ swaps the values of $s_i$ and $t_i$ for each $i$.

So if it turns out that you cannot pick $i_1, i_2$ so that $s_{i_1} + s_{i_2} \ge -(t_{i_1} + t_{i_2})$, then you can prove the result for $\{-r_k\}_{k=1}^n$ instead. And for that sequence $s_{i_1} + s_{i_2} \ge -(t_{i_1} + t_{i_2}), s_{i_1} + s_{i_2} \ge \frac s3$ will be true for some $i_1, i_2$, exactly because it wasn't ever true for the original sequence. And the truth of the theorem for this sequence immediately implies it was true for the original.

> Also when they set $r_1 = r_2 = r_3 = 1, r_4 = r_5 = r_6 = -1,$ why is $\frac{1}6$ the best possible value for the bound?

The condition requires you to pick at most two elements from $r_1, r_2, r_3$, and at least one element from $r_4, r_5, r_6$. That means the highest $\sum_{i\in S} r_i$ can be is $1 + 1 - 1 = 1$. And similarly the condition requires you to pick at least one element from $r_1, r_2, r_3$ and at most two elements from $r_4, r_5, r_6$, so the lowest $\sum_{i\in S} r_i$ can be is $1 - 1 - 1 = -1$.

So for any pick of index set $S$ meeting the condition, $\left|\sum_{i\in S} r_i\right| \le 1 = \frac 16\sum_{i=1}^n |r_i|$.